# how to use iterate mediator and aggregate mediator in one proxy service

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, xslt-2.0, wso2-esb

### Input XML

```
<Haer>
  <Hello>mani</Hello>
  <Hello>kishore</Hello>
</Haer>
```

### ProxyService

```
<inSequence>
   <iterate expression="//Haer/Hello" attachPath="//Haer" preservePayload="true" sequential="true" continueParent="false">
       <target>
       .
       . 
       .
       .
       </target>
   </iterate>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
   <property name="ROOT">
       <Haer></Haer>
   </property>
   <aggregate id="mm">
    <completeCondition timeout="">
    <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
    </completeCondition>
    <onComplete expression="//Haer/Hello" enclosingElementProperty="ROOT">
    <send/>
    </onComplete>
   </aggregate>
</outSequence>
```

### MyRequirement:

Upto Iterate mediator it is working fine. I am getting two splitted msgs as per the input XML.
1)

```
  <Haer>
     <Hello>mani</Hello>
  </Haer>
```

2)

```
  <Haer>
    <Hello>kishore</Hello>
  </Haer>
```

But what I want is getting the SameInput XML as the **final response**. The messages are being sent to target of the **'Iterate Mediator'** but then after I am not able get these splitted XML messages passed as Input to the **'AggregateMediator'**. So, please suggest me a way, whatever by adding extra proxy service or sequence to make these splitted msgs passed as inputs to 'Aggregate Mediator' of outSequence and get the desired response.
**Also please let me know if any Mistakes in the present code**

Please comment if Further clarification is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside iterate's target, add :

```
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
<sequence key="AggSequence"/>
```

move the content of your outSequence into a sequence named "AggSequence"